# Are 82°C to 98°C Temperatures extreme for a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, temperature

I've noticed that my 2018 MacBook Pro 15" with an i7 frequently hits 82°C while using Google Chrome and 98°C while playing video games. As an example, while running Minecraft with maybe 12 mods, Activity Monitor shows it using ~99% CPU with an energy impact of ~1000.

I got this MacBook in July and the issue started immediately. I contacted Apple Support who was quite unhelpful, telling me to reboot my computer and that they were "unable to find the safe temperatures" for my MacBook.

I haven't run into the MacBook throttling at all or shutting itself down, which leads me to believe something might be wrong with the firmware, or maybe the SMC. I haven't tried resetting the SMC yet, mostly due to concern over what specifically it will reset.

Since I'm not sure if these are extreme, should I be concerned for my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the Mid 2018 15" MacBook Pro with the Intel i7-8850H CPU. This CPU has a maximum junction temperature of 100°C.

That means that hitting 82°C while browsing or 98°C while gaming isn't a problem in itself. You're within the limits in the specification.

So unless you're actually experiencing some other kind of related problem besides that you think it is a high number, then there's really no issue at all - nothing to be worried about.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have the i7-8750H but I found the T-Junction on ark.intel.com and it was also 100°C.

Comment: I'm using *Macs Fan Control* to check the temperature, and the temperature I was going off of was the CPU PECI. I looked at the individual core temps while a game was running and saw them spike at exactly 100°C and then immediately go down to ~97°C, so I guess my MacBook might be throttling at the last second.

Comment: There’s nothing extreme running [right up to 100°C under load - especially if the other sensors are 40-60°range](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54422/)

Comment: Sure you won't damage, but it'll still thermal throttle to shit, and turn a $4k computer into a $1k performing one

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That's not entirely correct. You cannot know with the information at hand whether it "thermal throttles to shit". The original question does not say anything about performance problems. Having a temperature that climbs to 82C at some points while browsing doesn't mean any throttling is going on. If you're gaming for an extended amount of time with CPU usage at essentially 100% all the time, it is natural that some throttling takes place to keep the CPU temperature just below 100C. If the machine is slow, then yes, there's a problem and you'll want to look at the HW.

Comment: I own this exact model. It thermal throttles hard. You're correct about the distinction between peak and sustained loads, but saying "it is natural that some throttling takes place to keep the CPU temperature" is completely foolish. Apart from the [13" 6 core Dell offering](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2019/10/3/20897467/dell-xps-13-laptop-six-core-processor), and a limit number of other models, Apple is one of the only manufacturers who makes machines that intentionally prioritize quieter fans over sustained boost clocks. Throttling isn't normal. Especially on "Pro" models.

Comment: Well, I definitely disagree. As part of my job, I have used many different PC models, and regularly read detailed reviews and tests of laptops from Lenovo, HP and Dell (purchasing decisions) - and it is quite common that laptops employ some sort of throttling of the CPU. You might not like it, but it is just a fact today that you have to examine how much thermal capacity has before buying - you cannot just look at the CPU model and think "this is how fast it is" - it depends very much on how much heat it can move away.

Comment: In any case - the manufacturer designed the system to throttle under sustained loads - this means that the system works as designed. I.e. there's no need for the guy with the question to worry about having a corrupt firmware, non-functioning SMC or something like that. It's not the case.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I haven't noticed *any* performance problems. I've been able to run TensorFlow for more than an hour with no noticeable throttling. If you do have the same one as me and it throttles "to shit", I am truly sorry, but mine has had no such issues.

Comment: @MichaelP. Does that hit the GPU and CPU at the same time? That's when I notice the throttling. I don't think I've seen in in CPU-only or GPU-only loads. When you say "with no noticeable throttling", do you mean noticable as far as an end user might observe, or have you looked at the CPU clock-speeds during operation, and still couldn't see the diff?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica, I mean as far as I can tell. Honestly, I don't really care if it's throttling "to shit", because it obviously has no impact on whatever I'm trying to do.

Comment: Fair enough, though that depends on the thing being throttled. If it's some 3d model being rendered while you're out drinking coffee, it won't matter much. I notice it in dropped frames in video games, and noticeably slower compile times when doing clean builds (which are lengthy enough for the CPU to get hot and start throttling, unlike incremental builds). In any case, you're not "getting what you paid for"